RViz2 Text Markers Spacing Issue
I am trying to publish a Text Marker to RViz2 (ROS2 Humble). No matter which settings I choose, the text markers always seem to have inappropriate spacing (usually too big).
See image below. Notice how there is a huge space between Hello and RViz2. I would like to see a normal space here.

Here is a minimal example of what I am trying.
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from std_msgs.msg import Header, ColorRGBA
from builtin_interfaces.msg import Duration
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3

class TextPublisher(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('text_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(Marker, 'text_marker', 10)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.publish_text)  # Publish every second

    def publish_text(self):
        marker = Marker()
        marker.header = Header(frame_id="base_link", stamp=self.get_clock().now().to_msg())
        marker.ns = "text_marker"
        marker.id = 0
        marker.type = Marker.TEXT_VIEW_FACING
        marker.action = Marker.ADD
        marker.pose.position.x = 2.0
        marker.pose.position.y = 1.0
        marker.pose.position.z = 1.0
        marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0
        marker.text = "Hello RViz2!"
        marker.scale = Vector3(x=0.0, y=0.2, z=0.2)  # Only z is used, defines the height of the text
        marker.color = ColorRGBA(r=1.0, g=0.5, b=0.5, a=1.0)
        marker.lifetime = Duration(sec=0, nanosec=0)  # Permanent until updated or deleted

        self.publisher_.publish(marker)

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = TextPublisher()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Any ideas how to fix this?
I am using RViz version 11.2.12 (ROS 2).
Compiled against Qt version 5.15.3.
Compiled against OGRE version 1.12.1 (Rhagorthua).

https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/1261
